# List index out of range when trying to remove instance from list

Tags: python, list

The out of range error shows when I try to remove an instance from a list but doesn't pop up when I just pass the statement?

```
for x in range(len(urls)-1):
  if urls[x] == None:
    urls.remove(urls[x])
```

Comment: What would happen when x gets to (say) the last value in the range(index len(urls)-1), calculated once at the start of the loop, and an element had previously been removed, shortening the list?

Comment: Is your code deliberately not attempting to check the last entry in the list - try printing x and len(urls) and see what indexes it checks. I think you should be using range(len(urls)) if you want to check every item in the list.

Comment: Really you should be creating a new list (e.g. as BTables’s answer shows) and not modifying the list in-place.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're removing from the list while starting the loop executing `len(url) - 1` times. Total number of iterations will not be adjusted once you start removing from the list; and decreasing the length. Instead, you should use list comprehension for this.

```
new_list = [x for x in urls if x is not None]
```

Comment: Note the OP’s code doesn’t test the last entry in the list, (although maybe that’s not deliberate?) as posted it only iterates 0 to len(urls)-2.

Comment: Note: If `urls` must be modified in-place (e.g. `urls` is a function argument, and the design is C++ reference-like, where the caller's copy of the `list` passed as `urls` should be modified), matching the behavior of the OP's original code, it's still easy to do this with a listcomp + slice assignment, e.g. `urls[:] = [x for x in urls if x is not None]`

Answer (score 0):

This will happen even if there is a single `None` in your list.

The last index of the list which was valid before loop, will not be valid after popping a `None` because the list has shrunk by one.

Subsequent popping of your `None` element will result in subsequent shrinking of list and subsequent invalidity of 'second, third, fourth... from last' indexes.

Check workarounds here
[How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

**Edit**

The above code runs loop on `range(len(urls)-1)` which means if there are 4 elements in list, then it becomes range(0,3) and in turn iterates over 0, 1, 2 only. Hence, the last index is never reached.

So the error will come after popping the second `None`. However, the intention seems to traverse the whole list and hence `range(len(urls))` would be more appropriate in original code.

Comment: This won't break if 0 or 1 elements are popped. The loop is using `range(len(urls) - 1)`

Comment: @BTables Ah yes I forgot to consider that although I think this is not being intended but a logical error.